# I am trying to get the columns from an array but can be able to get it in laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to fetch the columns from another table through the id but whenever I do I get this error if I use `foreach` in the view

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myUniMentor\resources\views\userProfile\viewUserProfilePage.blade.php)

but if I run code without `foreach` command like `$users->reviews` I get the array of `review` table and also all the related content to that specific id and doing this `$users->reviews->comments` gives me an error

> Property [comments] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myUniMentor\resources\views\userProfile\viewUserProfilePage.blade.php)

My questions are:

1. How can I display the comments using the models?
2. How `$users->reviews` is returning only the columns associated with the id? is it because I passed the id in `belongsTo()`?

**ReviewController.php**

```
public function showUserProfile($id) {

        $users = User::find($id);

        // echo $users->first_name;

        return view('userProfile.viewUserProfilePage', compact('users'));
    }
}

 public function addNewReview($id) {

        $stars = Input::get("rating");
        $message = Input::get("message");

        // $users = User::find($id);

        $users = User::where('id', $id)->first();
        // echo $stars;
        // echo $message;
        // echo $users;
        // echo $users->id;
        // echo Auth::user()->id;
        // die();
        $reviews = new Review();
        $reviews->user_id = $users->id;
        $reviews->given_by = Auth::user()->first_name . ' ' . Auth::user()->last_name;
        $reviews->stars = $stars;
        $reviews->comments = $message;

        $reviews->save();

        Session::flash('message','Your Review has been added to the Mentor');
        return redirect('show-user-profile/' . $users->id);
    }
```

**show-user-profile.blade.php**

```
@section('content2')

<h3>Reviews</h3>
<p>{{ $users->reviews->comments }}</p> 

@endsection
```

**Review.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;

class Review extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'comments', 'stars', 'given_by',
    ];

    public function users()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id','id');
     }
}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

use App\UserType;
use App\Subject;
use App\SubjectKeyword;
use App\Review;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'type', 'username', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function getAllUsers() {
        return User::all();
     }

    public function userTypes()
    {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Users');
    }

    // public function subjects()
    // {
    //     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subject');
    // }

    public function subjects(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Subject','subject_id','id');
    }

    public function reviews(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
    }

    public function subjectKeywords(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\SubjectKeyword');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the following:

1. In your HTML

   ```
   @foreach($users->reviews as $review)
    <p>{{ $review->comments }}</p> 
   @endforeach
   ```
2. In your Review.php, Since a review belong to a User, Change to

   ```
   public function user()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
   }
   ```

Comment: Hello Bundayy Olayinka, thank you for your answer. This worked for me. I understood this but do you mind explaining this so that I know my understanding is right ?

Comment: Great. Based on your mapping, A User has many Reviews, so when you want to get the reviews of a user, you will get a collection, then to display each of them, you need to loop through the collection so you can display the comment in each review.  
For the second one, Since a Review belongs to a User, then you don't need to give it a plural function name, and you don't need to map it manually since you have a `user_id` field already.Laravel automatically picks the Model name concatenated with `_` and then the primary key, i.e `user_id` where `User` is the model and `id` is the primary key.

Comment: Thank you. I understood. I have one more question related to this if you could answer. if I have to fetch results from 3 different tables then ? e.g. in this case `$users->review->coments` is finding me comments so what if I add one more model before $users ? will that work ?

Comment: and how can I put the latest record on the top ? I tried orderBy but not working

Comment: to put latest at the top add `orderBy('created_at','desc')`. I didn't quite get the other question you're asking about getting data from another table. Maybe you should be more detailed

Comment: where am I exactly putting that `orderBy` ? As for second question I am getting all details from keyword table so e.g. its like `foreach($subjectKeyword as $f) {{ $f->users->first_name }}` which is working but when I want display a column from review table in it using the same logic i.e. `foreach($subjectKeyword as $f) {{ $f->users->reviews->average }}` or  `foreach($subjectKeyword as $f) {{ $f->users->reviews['average'] }}` it gives me the same error as in this post. I hope you understands now

Comment: I dont know why keep on facing the same issue. May be I am not understanding it well enough to implement it this way. '{{$f->users->reviews}}` does show all records from the table. Basically now facing the same issue as this post but on different page.

Comment: for the orderBy, do this in your foreach `$users->reviews->reverse() as $review`

Comment: i will need to see your code to help you with your other request

Comment: do I need to do that in views ? Should I update this post with that code too ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do in the blade file. But if you want to print all the comments of all the reviews of the user.

**Show user profile blade**

```php
@section('content2')

    <h3>Reviews</h3>
    @foreach($user->reviews as $review)
        <p>{{ $review->comments }}</p>
    @endforeach 

@endsection
```

**Explanation**

`reviews()` is a one to many relationship of a `user`, `$user->reviews` is a collection. So if you want to access any property of a `review` you need to loop through the collection.

Comment: thats already been fixed thank you for your answer. Can you please tell me how to order it by latest on the top ? I tried orderBy but not working